# Changing Img Src when clicked using event listener

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

Im creating a rock, paper,scissors project but using the water, fire and grass Pokemon instead of traditional Rock Paper Scissors. When I'm clicking the Pokemon of choice "choice" I want the player "player-pokemon" image to switch sources so it can Clearly be shown that it was the choice in the game. However when I try to do this with currentSrc, it won't switch in game.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Pokemon Battle</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <h1 class="title">Pokemon Battle</h1>
      <div class="computer container" id="computer-container">
        <h2>Gym Leader Score</h2>
        <p class="computer-score">0</p>
        <img
          src="pokeball.jpeg"
          id="computer-pokemon"
          class="computer pokemon"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="player container">
        <img src="pokeball.jpeg" id="player-pokemon" class="player pokemon" />
        <p class="player-score">0</p>
        <h2>Trainer Score</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="party container" id="choices">
        <img src="fire.jpeg" id="fire" class="choice" />
        <img src="water.jpeg" id="water" class="choice" />
        <img src="grass.jpeg" id="grass" class="choice" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
const choice = document.querySelectorAll(".choice");

const computerScore = document.querySelector(".computer-score");
const playerScore = document.querySelector(".player-score");

const computerChoice = document.getElementById("computer-pokemon");
let playerChoice = document.getElementById("player-pokemon");

let gymLeaderScore;
let trainerScore;

for (let i = 0; i < choice.length; i++) {
  choice[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
   
    // replace player pokeball with chosen pokemon
    var playerImg = choice[i].currentSrc;
    playerChoice.currentSrc = playerImg;
  });
}
```

[image: Project]

I have tried using a loop to collect the choice currentSrc and declare it as a variable playerImg and then make it equal playerChoice.currentSrc variable which is the element for the chose poke ball in img.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
let choicesImg = document.querySelectorAll(".choice");
let imgOfPlayer = document.getElementById("player-pokemon")

choicesImg.forEach(img => {
    img.addEventListener('click', e => {
        imgOfPlayer.src = e.target.src
    })
})

// You can also do it in one line of code like this:
choicesImg.forEach(img => img.onclick = e => imgOfPlayer.src = e.target.src )
```